# unwanted Chatter Daily Digest email

Tags: chatter

My chatter email settings are as follow:

```
Set frequency for personal digest:
Never
Set default frequency for groups I join:
Never
```

Yet I still receive `"Daily Digest for [me]"` and `"Daily Digest for [group I belong to]"` on my mail. I don't want them. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I have two accounts on sfdc, linked to aliases of the same mailbox. I was receiving emails for the second account.

Solved.

Answer (score 0):

The Set default frequency for groups I join: is only for groups you join after you check the box.

> Never Checkmark   Keep this default setting for all new groups. Whenever you join a group that you expect to monitor and contribute to actively, such as one for an important team or project, you can change to more frequent notifications for that specific group only.

You will need to go into each of the groups you joined prior to checking the box and on the left hand side select the email settings there.[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I do not have the option "Turn Off Group Email" and the Email Settings brings me back to the settings I am mentionning in my opening post...

Comment: Under the group settings on the email settings page, do you see a list of all the groups you are a member of? Are they all set to "Never"?

Comment: Yes I see them, and yes they are. Keep receiving unwanted emails though.

Comment: What happens if you turn off chatter emails all together or is that not an option?

Comment: I unchecked `Receive emails` and I still receive them! Can't believe it, I must be missing something, lol.

Comment: Hmm, do you have admin access? If yes, try going to setup -> manage users -> edit your user record. I've read about user records getting corrupted and that editing it can sometimes help.

Comment: Actually I contacted my admin and it turns out I have two accounts on sfdc, linked to aliases of the same mailbox, I was receiving emails for the second account. Kinda silly.
Thanks for your time anyway.